# JSON assistance

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I am looking for a little bit of guidance, tips and knowledge transfer. Currently I am practicing fetching JSON data, but I am having some issues.

My current problem I a running into is that my 3 variable (brand, desc and price) give me this error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Brand' of undefined**

Can someone help me with this, also tips on better coding would be nice.

```
var url = 'https://raw.githack.com/gromstone/jsonFiles/master/products.json';

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);

        $.each(data, function(i, products){

            var content = "<div class=\"item grid_4\">"; 

            $.each(products, function(i, mainProd){

                var brand = mainProd.ProductInfo.Brand,
                    desc = mainProd.ProductInfo.p_product_description,
                    price = mainProd.ProductInfo.p_product_price;

                //content += '<img class="scale-with-grid" src="' + src + '"/>';
                content += '<p>' + brand + desc + '</p>';
                content += '<p>' + price + '</p>';
                content += '<a>View More</a>';


            });

            content += "</div><!-- product -->";
            $('.load').append(parent);

        })
    },

    error: function(){
        alert('Data did not load, or no connection')
    }

});
```

You can see working code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/gromstone/j1etxuw0/1/

Also if anyone can provide additional help, I want to make a hover effect for each one of the 'div.items' where some additional data is shown on a separate div (ex 'div.placeHolder')

Thanks!

Comment: Set a breakpoint and inspect the structure of the value. Not being able to debug your code is like driving a car blindfolded. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you're looping over all properties of the object that your receive in the outer loop

```
$.each(data, function(i, products){
```

and in the inner loops you're expecting these properties to be arrays, and each array member to have a `ProductInfo` property:

```
$.each(products, function(i, mainProd){
  var brand = mainProd.ProductInfo.Brand,
```

However, the top-level properties of your JSON document are:

```
[ 
  "ProductsList", 
  "RecordsCount", 
  "nValue", 
  "Pages", 
  "Refinements", 
  "Breadcrumbs", 
  "CategoryName", 
  "sortProperty" 
]
```

So your program will first loop over the internals of `ProductsList` (what I guess is what you expected it to do), but after that, it will loop over the contents of `RecordsCount`, which in the JSON you linked does not contain an array but the number `8`. The inner loops in your program however expect it to be an array, and they will try to access a property `ProductInfo` of the (non-array) members, which will then fail with an error.

If you're only after iterating over the `ProductsList` of the JSON, removing the outer loop, and change the remaining (formerly inner) loop's `each` to:

```
$.each(data.ProductsList, function(i, mainProd){
```